# Why does the primary group of my user show up in /etc/group?

Tags: linux, fedora, group, etc, passwd

I'm following a course about Linux and it states the following: "The primary group of a user is not mentioned in the */etc/group* file."

However, my primary user "timgeldof" actually does show up in the */etc/group file*.
I have verified that the user indeed has "timgeldof" as primary group using the *id* and the *groups* command.

The rule stated in my course does apply for every other user though. Does it matter that the user timgeldof is the first user I created during installation?

Comment: you'd have to squint just the right way to interpret it correctly, perhaps as "the primary group of a user is not *dictated by* /etc/group, but by /etc/passwd (or the equivalent user database)"

Comment: The primary group is the group which automatically is used when creating new files/directories.

Answer (score 6):

The rule isn’t quite accurate; it should say

- on systems using `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, the primary group of a user is defined in `/etc/group` (this determines its identifier);
- a user doesn’t need to be listed as a member of his/her primary group.

As stated (in your question and in the version above), this doesn’t forbid your user appearing as a member of your primary group in `/etc/group`, because the *primary* group is defined in the user entry, not as a result of group membership. See [`man 5 passwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html):

> *GID*
>
> This is the numeric primary group ID for this user. (Additional groups for the user are defined in the system group file; see [`group(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)).

At least on Linux, when you log in, your group memberships are initialised as follows:

- your primary group is set to match your defined primary group (from `/etc/passwd` or wherever your user information is stored);
- your additional groups are set up to match the groups you’re a member of, and your primary group.

Thus it doesn’t matter whether your primary group lists you as a member or not.

Incidentally, it appears that, as you mention, the user created during installation is listed as a member of his/her primary group, on Fedora and presumably other distributions using Anaconda.